# Parse comment android one to many relations

Tags: java, android, parse-platform

I am trying to use parse to set comments for a specific post , I already have a Post class and a Comment class in the parse.com Data , anyway I tried to set a comment inside a column in the class and then get it , but the problem is , I can only get 1 comment per post , **how to do that , is my question** , I tried one to many relations , but it didn't work , I tried a pointer row in the Meal class that points to the Comment class , but I didn't know what to do then , here is some sample code :

```
 public void addTheComment() {



    // Create the Post object
    ParseObject post = new ParseObject("Post");
    post.put("textContent", txtComment.getText().toString());

    // Create an author relationship with the current user
    post.put("comment", getCurrentMeal());

    // Save the post and return
    post.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback () {

        @Override
        public void done(ParseException e) {
            if (e == null) {
                setResult(RESULT_OK);
                finish();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Error saving: " + e.getMessage(),
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
            }
        }

    });
```

this adds a comment from edit text through out a button when pressed

and here is the list that shows the comments :

```
 private void updateComments() {
    ParseQueryAdapter<ParseObject> adapter =
            new ParseQueryAdapter<ParseObject>(this, new ParseQueryAdapter.QueryFactory<ParseObject>() {
                public ParseQuery<ParseObject> create() {
                    // Here we can configure a ParseQuery to our heart's desire.
                    ParseQuery query = new ParseQuery("Post");
                    query.whereEqualTo("comment", getCurrentMeal());
                    return query;
                }
            });


    adapter.setTextKey("comment");
    adapter.setImageKey("photo");
    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

and :

```
public Meal getCurrentMeal() {
        return meal;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 private void updateComments() {
    ParseQueryAdapter<ParseObject> adapter =
            new ParseQueryAdapter<ParseObject>(this, new ParseQueryAdapter.QueryFactory<ParseObject>() {
                public ParseQuery<ParseObject> create() {
                    // Here we can configure a ParseQuery to our heart's desire.
                    ParseQuery query = new ParseQuery("Comment");
                    query.whereContainedIn("parent", Arrays.asList(mealId));
                    return query;
                }
            });


    adapter.setTextKey("content");
    //  adapter.setImageKey("photo");
    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

and when pressing the button (activate the method addTheComment) it adds the text from the edit text (txtComment)to insert it into the Comment section where you make a relation to the Post class.

```
public void addTheComment() {


// Create the comment
        ParseObject myComment = new ParseObject("Comment");
        myComment.put("content", txtComment.getText().toString());

// Add a relation between the Post with objectId "1zEcyElZ80" and the comment
        myComment.put("parent", ParseObject.createWithoutData("Meal", mealId));

// This will save both myPost and myComment
        myComment.saveInBackground();

    }
```

Comment: PS : still working on the update method , the list is still off (doesn't show the comments) , any help would be wonderful